# Pixels in my CSS

Tags: css

Currently my website is in pixels, and I have a lot of measurements in my CSS, with the px extension. As an example - padding: 50px 25px 25px 40px;

Is there a way, in the body tag, or elsewhere, to mention that the whole site will be in pixels, therefore foregoing the px extension that occurs so often in the CSS? So, my example would now be - padding: 50 25 25 40;

This way I save all those "px" characters, and my site loads correctly knowing it's pixel units...

Thanks in advance for any replies...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the unit is not optional unless your value is 0.

So, this is valid CSS :

```
.test {
  padding : 0;
}
```

This is also valid CSS :

```
.test {
  padding : 5px 0 0 2px;
}
```

But this is not valid CSS :

```
.test {
  padding : 5;
}
```

CSS does not provide a way to set the default unit and make `padding : 5;` a valid statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... too bad there is no solution, but this should be invented somehow. CSS is supposed to help save all those styling characters in a normal html page. So, it makes sense to somehow save the characters within the CSS page itself.

Comment: @nairb00 : It doesn't really matter as much as you think it does. If you take Bootstrap and minify it, you can reduce the size from 173.44 kb to 137.23 kb. Gzip it, and only 21.20 kb remains. — Now, remove all occurances of "px" from your Bootstrap file. The 173.44 kb before minification becomes 172.91 kb and the 137.23 kb after minification becomes 136.73 kb. That's a difference of only 0.5 kb. And if we also Gzip, we end up with a 21.16 kb file. That's only 0.04 kb less compared with if you didn't remove the "px" , which is a difference that's totally negligible!